# Load Google Maps in a tab when tab is picked, and not from begining

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, tabs

I have a TabLayout with 2 tabs.
First tab ( Main tab ) is a list of store in a listview
Second tab is the same list in a Google Maps.

I noticed that When I go by default in the first tab ( list ), the GPS icon appears in notification bar.

Thing is most of the time, user will use list and has no need to load so I think is a useless loss of Battery

How can I do to load my map on the moment the user click the second tab, and not from the initalization???

Here is my code:

```
public class FragmentTabsPdv extends BaseActivity {

    private ArrayList<Pdv> listaPdv;
    Adapter adapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs_pdv);

        PdvHandler db = new PdvHandler();
        listaPdv = db.getAllTiendas();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        if (ab != null){
            ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);

        }
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        if (viewPager != null) {
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if (tab.getText().equals("Mapa")){

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

    public ArrayList<Pdv> getListaPdv() {
        return listaPdv;
    }


    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter.addFragment(new ListPdvTabFragment(), "Lista");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment(), "Mapa");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

    }
```

MapPdvFragment.java

```
public class MapPdvTabFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
private MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap map;
private ArrayList<Pdv> pdvs;
private ViewPager pager;
private View fragmentView;
boolean showNoResults = false;
SharedPreferences prefs;
Context ctx;
private Pdv currentPdv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    ctx = getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag_map_pdv, container, false);
    fragmentView = v;

    Bundle localBundle = null;
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        localBundle = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("mapViewBundle");

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff

    mapView.onCreate(localBundle);
    mapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

    FragmentTabsPdv parent = (FragmentTabsPdv) getActivity();
    pdvs = parent.getListaPdv();

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    int zoom = 14;
    LatLng defaultLocation = null;
    for (Pdv pdv : pdvs) {
        if (pdv.getLatitude() != 0d) {
            defaultLocation = new LatLng(pdv.getLatitude(), pdv.getLongitude());
            break;
        }
    }
    if (defaultLocation == null || defaultLocation.latitude == 0.0d) {
        defaultLocation = new LatLng(23.6266557, -102.5375005);
        zoom = 5;
    }

    CameraUpdate here = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(defaultLocation, zoom);
    map.moveCamera(here);

    showNoResults = !(pdvs != null && pdvs.size() > 0);

    initPager();

    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            clickPdv(currentPdv);

        }
    });
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
    PdvHandler db = new PdvHandler();
    pdvs = db.getAllTiendas();

    displayPdvOnMap(pdvs); // Display markers
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mapView != null)
        mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mapView != null)
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

public void displayPdvOnMap(ArrayList<Pdv> tiendas) {
    map.clear();
    for (Pdv pdv : tiendas) {
        Marker marker = map
                .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(pdv.getLatitude(), pdv.getLongitude()))
                        .title(pdv.getTienda()).snippet(pdv.getCalle()));

        if (pdv.getDone() == 1)
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        else
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

        pdv.setMarker(marker);
    }
}

public void initPager() {

    pager = ((ViewPager) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.pager));
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int paramAnonymousInt) {
        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int paramAnonymousInt1, float paramAnonymousFloat, int paramAnonymousInt2) {
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            Pdv pdv = pdvs.get(position);
            if (pdv.getLatitude() != 0d) {
                Marker m = pdv.getMarker();
                m.showInfoWindow();
                // Center map on current marker
                CameraUpdate here = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(m.getPosition(), 14);
                map.animateCamera(here);
                // TODO Esta siendo un poco pesado la animacion
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        ctx.getString(R.string.tienda_no_geolocalizada),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

            }

        }
    });
    pager.setSaveEnabled(false);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter() {

        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup paramAnonymousViewGroup,
                                int paramAnonymousInt, Object paramAnonymousObject) {
            paramAnonymousViewGroup.removeView((View) paramAnonymousObject);
        }

        public int getCount() {

            if (showNoResults)
                return 1;
            if (pdvs != null)
                return pdvs.size();
            return 0;
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
            View view;
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (showNoResults) {
                view = li.inflate(R.layout.map_pager_empty, null);
            } else {
                view = li.inflate(R.layout.row_lista_pdv, null);
                final Pdv pdv = pdvs.get(position);
                TextView tienda_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tienda_name);
                TextView direccion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tienda_dir);

                String sucursal = pdv.getSucursal();
                String calle = pdv.getCalle();

                if (sucursal == null) {
                    sucursal = pdv.getTienda();
                    if (sucursal == null)
                        sucursal = ctx.getString(R.string.sin_nombre);
                }

                if (calle == null) {
                    calle = pdv.getCiudad();
                    if (calle == null)
                        calle = ctx.getString(R.string.sin_calle);
                }


                tienda_name.setText(sucursal);
                direccion.setText(calle);

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }

        public boolean isViewFromObject(View paramAnonymousView,Object paramAnonymousObject) {
            return paramAnonymousView == paramAnonymousObject;
        }
    };
    this.pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

}

/**
 * Manda a la captura o despliga infos de captura
 *
 * @param pdv el punto de venta actual
 */
private void clickPdv(final Pdv pdv) {
    ListPdvTabFragment lptf = new ListPdvTabFragment();
    lptf.openPdv(getActivity(), pdv, 0);
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    int i;
    i = getPdvPosition(marker);
    currentPdv = pdvs.get(i);

    if (i >= 0)
        pager.setCurrentItem(i, true);
    return false;
}

private int getPdvPosition(Marker marker) {
    int position = 0;
    for (Pdv pdv : pdvs) {
        Marker m = pdv.getMarker();
        String mId1 = m.getId();
        String mId2 = marker.getId();
        if (mId1.equals(mId2)) {
            return position;
        }
        position++;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String activityName = getClass().getSimpleName();
    prefs.edit().putString("FrontActivity", activityName).apply();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FragmentPagerAdapter will always load both of your fragments simultaneously (since the user could swype to the next tab in any moment), and you cannot make the number of preloaded Fragments less then 2 (one for each side).

If you want you can just initialize the map after the user landed on the "Mapa" Fragment using the onTabSelected callback that you've already overridden. I suppose now you are doing it in the onCreate, just move it in a method you'll call after the Fragment is visible.

Here's some code:

Change your setupViewPager so you keep the reference to the mapa Fragment:

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter.addFragment(new ListPdvTabFragment(), "Lista");
        //Add mMapaFragment as a member of the activity
        mMapaFragment = new Fragment();
        adapter.addFragment(mMapaFragment, "Mapa");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Then call a setupMap method in your mMapaFragment when it gets into view.

```
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // Check if your "Mapa" Fragment is selected, it's probably on position one
            if (arg0 == 1) {
               mMapaFragment.setupMap():
            }   
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Then load the map in the setUpMap() method.

Comment: I tried to override my Fragment in onTabSelected, but I had no successful result... any code suggestion?

Comment: I've added some to my answer, I cannot do more unless you put the code from your Mapa Fragment.

Comment: I added the Mapa Fragment code... I like your approach, but I can't find a way to do it without getting a NPE in Mapa Fragment

Comment: There are multiple issues in your code, but first things first: you can avoid the null pointer exceptions if you always check if mapView is null before calling the life cycle methods (mapView.onCreate, onPause etc.). Then move everything that initializes the map (from findViewById(R.id.map) to return v) to a method you'll call later. It should work.

Comment: You should also try to make these changes: you shouldn't use setRetainInstance  in this case, it changes the life cycle of the Fragment and messes with the life cycle of the MapView. Also, if you need a Context in a Fragment, use the onAttach method that passes you the activity instead of calling getActivity on onCreate.